# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.sitename.com,' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cors, web-config

I have added the following in the web.config file to enable cross origin resource sharing in ASP.Net MVC Project but still it is not supporting CORS.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
           <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: You have to make sure to have "restrict domains" turned off or have valid URLs defined in Mautic's configuration page under "CORS Settings."

Answer (score 0):

Please try enabled cors in Global.asax as shown below.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)  
{  
    EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,POST");  
    config.EnableCors(cors);  
}
```

and give access controller level using

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]  
public class LoginController : ApiController  
{  

}
```

you will need to add the package for cors from nuget as well.

Comment: I cannot modify any controller or global file. I just need to get data from a json file to my site

Comment: try read this : [link]( http://sibeeshpassion.com/fix-to-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-or-working-with-cross-origin-request-in-asp-net-web-api/ )